# How to download Playonlinux through terminal?

Tags: playonlinux

I can't go to the playonlinux website. Can someone tell me how to install playonlinux through terminal? I would install Playonlinux through Ubuntu Software Center but i dont think it will update it. I'm running Ubuntu Unity 12.04 LTS which is Precise.

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`?

Comment: Yea but i need the repository. I can't go to the playonlinux website for some reason to check what it is.

Comment: Add this to your software sources: `deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main`.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JYJ3gd6.png

Comment: in my case it is in the std repository ` http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse`

Comment: Can someone go to http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html and scroll down to the Precise version and copy and paste everything?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/70FS6ci.png doesnt work

Comment: man just install `wine` via `apt` and download the file http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.2.5/PlayOnLinux_4.2.5.deb

Comment: Yea but playonlinux downloads wine for you and i dont want to install wine twice and it get messed up or something.

Comment: NO it is just one single `.deb` archive. You install wine and the install this package using `dpkg -i <whatever>`. See also: I have edited my comment: it is `apt-add-repository <whatever>` you can show all posibilitys using `apt-<TAB>`.

Comment: Umm you cannot install PoL without Wine.  PoL is a wrapper not a stand alone.

Answer (score 3):

`virusboy@virusboy-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo apt-get install playonlinux
[sudo] password for virusboy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libwxgtk-media2.8-0 python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion
Suggested packages:
  scrot wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples editra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libwxgtk-media2.8-0 playonlinux python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,949 kB of archives.
After this operation, 27.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

This is what you should see.  Since PlayonLinux is a wrapper for Wine, you need the Wine PPA.  To do this in a terminal type in the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

to add the PPA repository to your ever growing list of PPAs and update the list.  Now you can use the command without issue.

Comment: @LittleByBlue: Incorrect comment removed!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are new repositories for such installation. You will need to run:

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```